# How to create an infinite grid in Flutter with InteractiveViewer?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, grid, interactive

I would like to create an infinite interactable grid in Flutter where I can place nodes/elements on.

I attempted to utilize InteractiveViewer with a CustomPainter which paints a grid as its child. It provides the desired functionality, but the panning action affects the grid itself, resulting in the grid disappearing during panning.

The code I have now:

```
    /// Represents the diagram canvas widget.
class DiagramCanvas extends ConsumerWidget {
  const DiagramCanvas({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, _) {
        final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.white, // Set your desired background color

          // Create an InteractiveViewer for panning and zooming
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            panEnabled: true,
            scaleEnabled: true,
            boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
            minScale: 0.5,
            maxScale: 2.0,
            child: SizedBox.fromSize(
              size: Size.infinite,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: ClipRect(
                      child: CustomPaint(
                        size: Size(screenSize.width * 2, screenSize.height * 2),
                        painter: DiagramGridPainter(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Grid Problem]

What would I need to add or change to achieve my goal?